# Angularjs xeditable typehead not updating the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, x-editable

Am using angular xeditable typehead directive to show autocomplete drop down. I am fetching data from a json file on page and using the jso array for e-typeahead. It is showing the matching values from array when I type something in input type. But when I select any value from list it is not updating the model as well as view.My file are looks like following:

conroller.js

```
var payApp = angular.module('payRoll', ["xeditable", "ui.bootstrap"]);

payApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window,$location, $filter) {
$scope.Zip_City_options = ["1000  BOURG EN BRESSE",
    "1000  BROU",
    "1000  ST DENIS LES BOURG",
    "1090  AMAREINS",
    "1090  AMAREINS FRANCHELEINS CES",
    "1090  CESSEINS",
    "1090  GENOUILLEUX",
    "1090  GUEREINS",
    "1090  LURCY",
    "1090  MONTCEAUX",
    "1090  MONTMERLE SUR SAONE",
    "1100  APREMONT",
    "1100  ARBENT",
    "1100  BOUVENT",
    "1100  GEOVREISSET",
    "1100  OYONNAX",
    "1100  VEYZIAT",
    "1110  ARANC",
    "1110  BRENOD",
    "1110  CHAMPDOR",
    "1110  CORCELLES"];
   });
```

And html is like:

```
<div  ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <span  class="list-group-item">
      <a href="#" ng-model="zip_code" editable-text="zip_code" e-typeahead="city for city in Zip_City_options | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
         {{ zip_code || '58.29C' }}
      </a>                       
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller to following

```
    var payApp = angular.module('payRoll', ["xeditable", "ui.bootstrap"]);

    payApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window,$location, $filter) {
    $scope.Zip_City_options = ["1000  BOURG EN BRESSE",
        "1000  BROU",
        "1000  ST DENIS LES BOURG",
        "1090  AMAREINS",
        "1090  AMAREINS FRANCHELEINS CES",
        "1090  CESSEINS",
        "1090  GENOUILLEUX",
        "1090  GUEREINS",
        "1090  LURCY",
        "1090  MONTCEAUX",
        "1090  MONTMERLE SUR SAONE",
        "1100  APREMONT",
        "1100  ARBENT",
        "1100  BOUVENT",
        "1100  GEOVREISSET",
        "1100  OYONNAX",
        "1100  VEYZIAT",
        "1110  ARANC",
        "1110  BRENOD",
        "1110  CHAMPDOR",
        "1110  CORCELLES"];

    $scope.model = {
       zip_code: null
    };
});
```

Change your markup to following

```
    <div  ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <span  class="list-group-item">
    <a href="#" editable-text="model.zip_code" e-typeahead="city for city in Zip_City_options | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
          {{ zip_code || '58.29C' }}
   </a>                  

   </span>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. Actually the problem was my lib files are older versions.

Comment: Can I have a support for this ? Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31319561/xeditable-grids-drop-down-values-cannot-change-from-the-outside-dropdown