# xeditable Grid's drop down values cannot change from the outside dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) angular directive.I need to set the grid's all the drop down values of `Status` column according to the value of the outside drop down.
I have set up the [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/9130/).But it's not working.Could you tell me Why ? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** When I click the `cancel` button then it's updated.Very strange :( Could you tell me how to sort out this issue ?

**HTML**

```
<span editable-select="bulkPaymentType" e-form="tableform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses" e-ng-change="setBulkPaymentType($data)">
 </span>
```

**js**

```
 $scope.setBulkPaymentType = function (data) {
        for (var i = $scope.users.length; i--;) {
            var user = $scope.users[i];
            user.status = data;
        };
    };
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/9130/)**

Comment: I'll take a look at it in a sec. Figuring out something on my end really quick.

Comment: Still looking into this. I was slammed here so I haven't had as much time as I'd like. I can look at it first thing tomorrow if thats fine by you, lemme know.

Comment: Yes,sure.Please let me know if you find out the solution for this.Thanks in advance @KreepN

Comment: Hi @KreepN I have found the solution.I'll update it here later.Thanks for your support :)

Comment: I'd like to see it. Been looking at this for the last 30 mins.

Comment: Yes sure.I'll update it and let you know.Thanks a lot for your Great support friend @KreepN :)

Comment: @KreepN I have put the answer.Please see that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.Here it is :)

***HTML***

```
<span editable-select="bulkPaymentType" e-form="tableform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses" e-ng-change="setBulkPaymentType($data,tableform)">
 </span>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.setBulkPaymentType = function (data,tableform) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tableform.$editables.length; i++) {
            if (tableform.$editables[i].name === 'user.status') {
                tableform.$editables[i].scope.$data = data;

            }
        }
    };
```

***Play with it :*** **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/9187/)**

Comment: Looks good, I didn't know that it stored the data somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @KreepN.Yes, we can learn lot if we explore their `xeditable.js` file :)

Answer (score 0):

Your setBulkPaymentType method is updating the users in your controller scope.
But the value in the editable input is actually a copy from your controller scope. So when you call setBulkPaymentType, you don't see them change. And when you hit cancel button, the form will display with the value in your controller scope which you updated with setBulkPaymentType, that is the reason. I don't think you can modify the $data within each editable directly since they are using isolated scope. There is no way to get access to $data from outside.

Comment: I have found the solution.Please see the answer :)